# No WiFi or ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless

I am trying to switch from windows to Linux for the first time. Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately, the installer connected to my WiFi fine but Ubuntu proper doesn’t. Ethernet doesn’t work either. A friend suggested runnning dmesg, which gave the result

iwlwifi ... no suitalbe adapter found.

I have a

ASUS Dual-Band Wireless AC1200 Bluetooth 4.0 PCI-E Adapter PCE-AC55BT

. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should install all the third party packages at the begining. Otherwise it won't work after the installation. Tick all the checkboxes in first few dialogs during the installation

Comment: @dedunumax I did check those. In fact as soon as it booted I got an error saying it wasn't able to download the extra material.

Comment: nope during the installation did u do that? Installer can connect to wifi and ethernet most of the times

Comment: @dedunumax I'm sure I checked them in the installer... but if you are sure that's it, I can wipe + reinstall. Might try 17.10.

Comment: You better try 16.04 then move to 17.10 if it doesnt work. because if it is a proprietary driver 17.10 also won't support it.

Comment: If you have usb3 and usb 2 use a usb3 pen drive and plug it to usb3 slots